# Coatings on spacecraft structures

Tags: spacecraft, materials, structural-design, outgassing

Traditionally, aluminium spacecraft structures have been alodine-coated to protect the surface from corrosion and resistance to scratches.

[image: Alodined coating on satellite UHF/VHF receiver by Spaceteq]

However, the last few years I've noticed that more and more structures are anodised instead. This confused me, because although it provides a corrosion-resistant non-conductive coating (not to mention a cool colour!), wouldn't a lot of outgassing occur from the anodise coating?

[image: Anodised Ion Thruster by Orbion]

Appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Comment: there's soe mention of alodine and other coatings in [this answer to *Cubesat surface material*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53744/12102)

Comment: Thanks for the link @uhoh!